# How to do a subquery in yii2 framework with active record?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I need to do this with yii2 framework and I could'nt find anything on the web.

I need to execute and 'AND' and 'OR' within a where like this:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fecha_creacion', $this->fecha_creacion])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fecha_reapertura', $this->fecha_reapertura])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fecha_clausura', $this->fecha_clausura])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'observacion', $this->observacion])
            ->andFilterWhere(function($query) {
                $query->where(['like', 'estudiantes.nombres', $this->estudiante]);
                $query->orWhere(['like', 'estudiantes.apellidos', $this->estudiante]);
            });
```

But this does'nt work. So my question is how to do it? with the active record of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fecha_creacion', $this->fecha_creacion])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fecha_reapertura', $this->fecha_reapertura])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fecha_clausura', $this->fecha_clausura])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'observacion', $this->observacion])
            ->andFilterWhere([ 'OR',
                               ['like', 'estudiantes.nombres', $this->estudiante],
                               ['like', 'estudiantes.apellidos', $this->estudiante]
            ]);
```

Comment: Amazing! Where did you find that ? It works ver well. Thank you!